# Why is my boat stuck, and how can I unstick it?

Tags: openttd

I have a boat that goes between an oil rig (Dreningbury Valley) & a dock, I also have a hover boat that goes between multiple oil rigs. For some reason both of these boats got stuck at a single rig (Dreningbury Valley). It's very bizarre:

[image]

I've tried changing their destination to the depot, changing their destination to another rig, skipping a destination, removing all destinations and starting over, creating a closer depot for them to go to, etc. None of these actions have helped. I was hoping that this rig would eventually disappear form lack of activity, but it still registers a ~20% transport rate for both oil and passengers, so I doubt it's going to go away.

Comment: when the boat is stuck and you click on them, what does it say that they are currently doing for orders?

Comment: It says they're heading to the ship depot because that's where I tried to send them. If I try to send them to the rig, that's what it says "Heading for..."

Comment: it could be they're just too close together so there's no room to manuever?

Comment: Boats frequently drive over each other all the time.

Comment: @yx, it could be that the 2 oil rigs are just so close they can't maneuver, but then how did the boats get in there in the first place?

Comment: no clue, but how did you get 3 rigs to appear so close like that

Comment: @yx, I didn't build them, they just seemed to build themselves. I do allow more than 1 type of industry / town.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could remove the stuck ship was to use the magic bulldozer to remove the offending oil rigs (Dreningbury Exchange and Dreningbury Valley). This made the ships free to move once again.